# Displaying, deleting Objects in a JList

Tags: arraylist, jframe, jlist

So, I've got this Object called Person, with "ID", "Name", "Surname", "Mark" and want to "save" everything as a new Person in `List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();`

I have a JButton where I'd like to be able to add a new Person. 
What I have done is:

`personJList.add(personJList, new Person(idJTF.getText(), nameJTF.getText(), surnameJTF.getText(), markJTF.getText()));`

but for that, I had to

`JList personJList = new JList(personList.toArray());
JScrollPane personListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(personJList);`

I cannot display the new Person in the JList. How can I make this happen?

And: How can I then delete a person from this JList/ArrayList then?

Answer (score 1):

- Make an instance of `DefaultListModel`, maybe keep it as a instance field of your class
- Seed it with you existing values
- Apply this to your `JList`
- When you need to, use the `DefaultListModel` to add new objects, it will automatically update the `JList`

See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more detalils